# SSRS Legend with Set Rows and Columns

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to figure out whether this can be done simply or whether its more complicated.

I need a legend for a pie\donut chart where I can specify the number of columns and rows in the legend. This needs to be dynamic as the series values will change, so one pie might have Geography, one might be Industry, and so on.

So as an example, the legend will be underneath the donut, and have 2 columns of 5 values. Excuse the nasty screenshot.
[donut with 10 series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZpYA.png)

If there are less than 10 series values, it needs to look like this.
[donut with 6 series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8dIe.png)

The slight caveat here is that the 10th series might by "Other" so I will be using the CollectedStyle option.

If it can't be done with a legend, any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the layout behavior of the legend in the properties. This gives you a little more control over how they display with different numbers of series. If you have issues with long series names wrapping, you can truncate them to keep the layout in line.

[image]

If it's that important and this still doesn't work, the last resort would be to use a matrix to control the layout. You could use a `ROW_NUMBER` function to determine the row number and column number of each series. The matrix would be grouped on rows and columns by these ID's. The really tricky part is that you would then need to also figure out the exact colors in the palette up to the limit of allowable series. So it's probably not worth the extra effort.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the reply. I'm on a client vpn at the minute so I can't see your image but will have a look when back in the office. The colours won't be an issue as a custom palette is being used.